# SQL REPLACE giving error: 'String or binary data would be truncated.'

Tags: sql-server, replace, truncate

I'm trying to replace just part of a string in our company database. The column in which I'm trying to update is `MERGECODES (varchar(20),null)`. A typical value of this column would be something like `'M, GPE, T'`.

I would like to replace every instance of `T` with `KD` but I'm getting the error below. It will allow me to change anything with the same number of characters or less, for example, it will allow me to replace `T` with `K` but not with `KD`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys!

Code:

```
UPDATE GoldMine.dbo.CONTACT1 
SET MERGECODES = REPLACE(MERGECODES, 'T', 'KD')
```

ERROR:

> *Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
>
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.*

Comment: If you really have `M, GPE, T` in a `varchar(20)` column, and you execute your `REPLACE` - it just works without any problem. I'm thinking that you're probably updating **too many rows** and at least one of the rows your `UPDATE` statement hits contains too many characters in that column for the `REPLACE` to work. Try to use a `WHERE id = 42` or something clause - in order to update **just a single row** which you know is OK.

Comment: **Why did someone down vote this question? Please let me know if I did something wrong here.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to increase your data type size.

Currently you have `varchar(20)`.

If the data is 20 characters long, and you replace 1 character for 2, then that will be 21 characters long, which will cause [truncation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation).

Try increasing your data type to `varchar(50)` for example, and this should resolve your problem.